# ExtJS 6 Filter store of grid by lastname or middlename

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, store, extjs6

I'm new to ExtJS.
I have a store of a grid that has a column **FullName** and I want to filter the store by lastname or middlename.
I have used this code

```
tbar: [
    'Search', {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        listeners: {
            specialkey: function(field, e) {
                if(e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                    var texto = field.getValue();
                    store_Pessoas.removeFilter('filtersIdPessoasValor');
                    if(isNaN(texto)) {
                        store_Pessoas.addFilter({
                            id: 'filtersIdPessoasValor',
                            property: 'tFullName',
                            value: texto
                        });
                    store_Pessoas.load();
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

With this code I can only filter by firstname and onwards, but I want to filter by middlename or lastname.

Answer (score 0):

Your grid can have a column "FullName", but your store should have separate fields for firstname, middlename and lastname. Otherwise you'll just have to assume that the fullname is in a consistent format to be able to filter it on the basic of middle and lastname.

you can use filterBy to write your own custom filter function -

```js
var texto = field.getValue();
store_Pessoas.clearFilter();
if (isNaN(texto)) {
  store_Pessaoas.filterBy(function(record) {
    var fullname = record.get('FullName');
    //Assuming that your name has a structure of FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME LASTNAME
    var names = fullname.split(" "); //splits the string into an array of 3
    // names[1] - middlename / names[2] - lastname
    if (names[1].toLowerCase().indexOf(textto.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || names[2].toLowerCase().indexOf(textto.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
};
```

Checkout the docs for filterBy
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-filterBy